# I'm uploading a video to a server in the background, what happens if I delete the video that's being uploaded?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, post, server

I am a mobile developer.
I have a question, I'm post a video to the server and That video is uploading in the background.
In android, I'm using [services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) to do that.
what happens if I delete the video that's uploading?
Does it have an error?
What will happen? and What should i do in this case?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I guess it will fail to upload, as the source has gone. You should show an error explaining that the upload failed.

Comment: Isnt the video like packaged and then send to the server so even if you delete the Video the Server still can download it because it got send everything beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how the app works. If the app opens the video file and keeps it open until it has been totally uploaded it should be possible to delete the file while it uploads without effect on the upload.

On Linux deleting a file that is in use is possible and has no effect on programs that have the file opened. Only if the program closes the file and tries to reopen it, it can no longer access it as it has been deleted.

Therefore if you want to make your app resistant against deleted videos, make sure to get any file information and cache them within your app and keep the InputStream (or whatever you use for reading the file data) open unless the file has been uploaded completely.

If the upload is in progress your app should no longer need and `File`, `Path` or what ever ReactNative uses to reference to the uploaded file.